# Is there an algebraic way to estimate the x value?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

The equation is $e^x = x^2 - 2$.
I know the answer is $x\approx -1.49$
from searching the equation online but
the way it showed the solution was just drawing the graphs.
is there a way to estimate it by isolating the x?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4103156/how-to-solve-e-x2-2) for an estimate. It also works for $e^x=x^2-2$.

Comment: There is no algebraic way that I know of that will solve this for $x$.  You could estimate it by bisection or using a Taylor polynomial, but the latter is beyond precalculus.